# Matplotlib.pyplot: Open new figure environment

Tags: python, matplotlib

In pyplot, when I run `plt.plot(x)`, it seems to internally run the following logic:

1) If a figure is already open, use that figure, otherwise create a new one.
2) If an axes in that figure is already open, use that axes, otherwise create a new one.
3) Plot on that axis.

I'm wondering how I can force step (1) to open up a new figure the next time some plotting command is called.  Something like

```
plt.plot(x1)
with new_figure_environment():  # Ensure that plot commands within this go to new figures
    some_function()
plt.show()
```

If `some_function` contains:

```
def some_function():
    plt.plot(x1)
```

Then I want to open up a new figure, but if it does not contain a plot function then I do not.

Comment: Why would you type `with new_figure_environment():` in your code if you don't plot anything to the new figure? In reverse that means that if you want something plotted to a new figure, you type `plt.figure()`; if you don't want to plot anything to a new figure, you don't type `plt.figure()`.

Comment: Maybe `plt.get_fignums` will help you.  It returns a list of existing figure numbers.  It returns a list of length-zero if there are no existing figures.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I don't necessarily know in advance what code is going to be called in my environment.  In my case, in the `with` block, I call a display function, which is specified elsewhere and which may or may not use matplotlib.

Comment: In this case call `plt.figure()` inside of your `display` function.

Comment: I may not be the one in control of the display function.

Comment: I rephrased to clarify

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot in a specific figure number your figure using `fig1 = plt.figure(1)`, `fig2 = plt.figure(2)` etc. 
To plot a graph in a specific figure define axes `ax1 = fig1.gca()` gca = get current axis and instead of using `plt.plot()` use `ax1.plot()` to plot in the figure 1

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x1 = [0,1]
x2 = [0,2]

y1 = [0,1]
y2 = [0,-1]

fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig1.gca()

fig2 = plt.figure(2)
ax2 = fig2.gca()


ax1.plot(x1,y1,'b')
ax2.plot(x2,y2,'r')

plt.show()
```

If you want to create 5 figures use lists :

```
fig = []
ax = []
for i in range(5) :
    fig.append(plt.figure(i))
    ax.append(fig[i].gca())
```

if the figure 1 is already opened and you want to plot an additional curve you just have to type these lines :

```
fig3 = plt.figure(1)
ax3 = fig1.gca()
ax3.plot(x1,y2,'g') 
fig3.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: That will create 2 figures regardless of whether a plot command is called which is not what the OP wants

Comment: If the figure 1 is already open and he wants to add an additionnal plot in this figure he can just type for example in python shell :
`ax1.plot(x1,y2)` and then `fig1.canvas.draw()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but that's not quite what I need.  I rephrased the question to clarify.